Android SDK file not found android jar for Platform 35
I am using Flutter on MacOs. I have all the dependencies installed but still doctor fails.
rushikant@Rushikants-MacBook-Pro ~ % flutter doctor                                                    
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    ✗ Android SDK file not found: /Users/rushikant/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-35/android.jar.



How can i find `android.jar` file..?? Thank you all in advance.


have you installed android studio ?

Yes.. I have installed android studio latest Lady bug release. Bash has sdk path as well..!!

it seems you have not installed Android 35 SDK, or it's broken. Try:

Open Android Studio.
Go to Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK.
Select the SDK Platforms tab.
Select and install(click apply) Android 35 SDK version.




Please try uninstalling and installing Android 15.0 from sdk manager again. It did work for me.
